# Windows 8.1 update error 0xc1900101(0x2000c)

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8-upgrade

I have wanted to update my Windows 8 to 8.1 and get an error. Here is the error from the WindowsUpdate.log: http://pastebin.com/4cebcqbW

Comment: Googling the error code from your log leads back to this site and a potential problem with TrueCrypt, is your computer encrypted?

Comment: No, I have not used any encription program.

Comment: I think you probably looked this up already, just making sure. You took a look at this, right? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/cannot-upgrade-windows-8-to-windows-81-getting/9ce5f7b0-4f87-4a22-be21-3ec096d3281f

Answer (score 1):

```
0xC1900101-0x2000C
           0x2017C
           0x20007
```

THERMAL SHUTDOWN. Clean your PC cooling system, or put your computer in a cold place.